# How do I change the color of the Scrollbar in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar

```
scrollbar_table = Scrollbar(master, orient=VERTICAL,)
scrollbar_table.config(command=self.table_view.yview, bg = 'black', activebackground= 'black')
scrollbar_table.grid(row=4, column=1, rowspan= 1, sticky= NS)
```

This is what I have tried and these are the imports I have used in my Code:

```
import requests
from tabulate import tabulate
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from tkinter import ttk
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
```

So I got the needed packages. I don't get an error, but the color of the scrollbar is just default. I want to change the color of the Scrollbar and the Scrollbar Background. I don't have to change if I hover over it.

I also looked through Documentations and also sought the help of ChatGPT.

Comment: What platform are you running this on? Some platforms (OSX for sure, maybe Windows?) won't let you change the color of the tk scrollbar. You might try using the ttk.scrollbar with a custom theme.

Comment: My OS is Windows 11. I code and run it from VS Code (that shouldnt make a difference right?) and i have Python 3.12 installed. But i got the same Problem with Python 3.11. I will try it with the ttk Scrollbar, thanks

Comment: @toyotaSupra i already tried that but i didnt really understand how the canvas worked and focused on the ttk.style and scrollbar widget. But thanks, i think i will start a project to learn how to use canvas.

Comment: Actuall. yu haven't mentioned about canvas in your queston.

Answer (score 1):

Ever considered customtkinter?

Check this example

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as ctk

root = ctk.CTk()
root.geometry('400x400')

frame = ctk.CTkScrollableFrame(root,
                               orientation=tk.VERTICAL,
                               fg_color='teal',
                               scrollbar_button_color='orange',
                               scrollbar_button_hover_color='darkorange',
                               corner_radius=10,
                               label_text='Scrolled Data',
                               label_fg_color='#46ADF0'
                               )
frame.pack()

for i in range(50):
    ctk.CTkLabel(
        frame,
        text=f'label nr. {i}',
        font=ctk.CTkFont('Consolas', 14, 'bold')
    ).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: OP didn't ask about `customtkinter`.

Comment: @ovski that helped me a lot. It somehow worked and dont worked. so i just moved the root window and now the ttk.style works so i dont need the customtkinter for the Scrollbar anymore but i used it for a progressbar later. Thanks for showing me this libary i never heard of it before but i think its pretty useful. At least my code works now.

Comment: I've known about it for a while, but only recently started to use it. The main reason is the scroll frame. I'm sure you've found it by now, but if not, here is the link to the [Custom Tkinter Wiki](https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/)